# null error when trying to print bridge game

Tags: java

I am getting a java null error on this line when I run main

```
int rank = cards[i].getRank();

int points = cards[i].getPoints();
```

I am simply trying to get the countHighCardPoints() point values of the cards in the hand array and add the points to a sum.
I am also going to assume my countDistributionPoints() will work if I was not also getting a null on `char suit = cards[i].getSuit();`

Thus my **Hand** class which I need help on.

```
public class Hand
{

 //Holds an array of card objects
 private Card [] cards = new Card [13];

/**
 * Constructor takes array of Cards and assigns that parameter to
 * the instance variable
 */
public Hand(Card [] cards)
{
    Card [] hand = cards;
}

/**
 * Looks through each card in hand array and adds its points
 * if the card has any to a sum highPoints
 */
public int countHighCardPoints()
{
    int highPoints = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {

        int rank = cards[i].getRank();
        int points = cards[i].getPoints();

       highPoints += points;

    }

    return highPoints;
}


public int countDistributionPoints()
{
    int countPoints = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        //char suit = cards[i].getSuit();

        if (cards[i].getSuit() >= 3)
            countPoints = 0;
        else if (cards[i].getSuit() == 2)
            countPoints++;
        else if (cards[i].getSuit() == 1)
            countPoints += 2;
        else if (cards[i].getSuit() == 0)
            countPoints += 3;
    }

    return countPoints;
}
```

**Deck** class for reference

```
public class Deck
{
//Holds an array of card objects
private Card [] cards  = new Card [52];

//Holds number of cards remaining in deck
private int count;


/**
 * Creates a Card [] arrayOfCards which is 13 cards for each player 
 * and will determine number of cards that was dealt with count.
 */
public Card [] dealThirteenCards()
{
    Card [] arrayOfCards = new Card [13];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 12 && count < 52; i++) {
        arrayOfCards[i] = cards[i];
        count++;
    }

    return arrayOfCards;
}
```

Comment: `private Card [] cards = new Card [14];` - since when does a Bridge hand have fourteen cards?

Comment: must be a typo on my part, will change asap.

Comment: So you don't get a `NullPointerException` when you say `cards[i].getRank()` but you get a `NullPointerException` when you say `cards[i].getPoints()`? Not sure if that is possible unless the issue is in the code inside the `getPoints` method itself. Can you show the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @ChetanKinger Well I do get the null error for both `cards[i].getRank()`  and `cards[i].getPoints()` I just had one of them commented out at the time I ran my main.

Comment: Don't you think that's relevant information you should be posting as part of your question? Also 'Card [] hand = cards'. What exactly is this lone doing? I have a feeling you are not showing us the code that you are actually running. We can't help you when you do this.

Comment: @ChetanKinger  The constructor is supposed to do this -> _Takes 
one parameter which is an array of Cards. 
Its only action is to assign that 
parameter to the instance variable._

Comment: That's the issue with you code. You are not initializing the instance variable. You are initializing a local variable. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Still playing around with your code, but currently I have identified something here:

1.In your Hand's construct, you never assign the value you pass in to its instance variable cards, that's why the deck under each Hand will be an array of nulls. You should change it to:

```
public Hand(Card [] cards) {
    this.cards = cards;
}
```

2.The `dealThirteenCards` under Deck behaves abnormally.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 13 && count < 52; i++) {
    arrayOfCards[i] = cards[i];
    count++;
}
```

After you have initialized Deck, the count will be -1. Above code will be executed 4 times for 4 players, each time assigned 14 cards to each player. **The count will be -1 + 4*14 = 55 if ends properly, which is more than 52.** So your for loop will terminate earlier than expected. That indicates the 4th player of you Game will not get the final 3 cards I think.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Each player (up to 4) will get 13 cards each and each card that is placed into the array will add +1 to the count.

Comment: @KrakenJaws The count in Deck will always be -1 after you have initialized the Deck, is that a proper value for count?

Comment: I assume a 0 would be more reasonable and I know the error is within  changing `count = 51-13;` to `count = 52-13;` and so forth for `count = 38-13;` to `count = 39-13;` incrementing the left number by 1. When I check count I get 14 cards dealt though.

Comment: @KrakenJaws I have updated my answer. Your code will not assign the last 3 cards to the 4th player and hence cause null value.

Comment: I am now getting 13 cards for count and 0 when no cards are dealt this instance seems to look better now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the following code. Instead of initializing the instance variable, you end up initializing a local variable.

`Card [] hand = cards;`

Change this to :

`this.cards=cards`

Answer (score 1):

```
private Card[] cards = new Card [13];
```

This creates an array of 13 elements. All the elements are null unless you loop through each index and initialize it with a new Card.

```
public Hand(Card [] cards) {
    Card[] hand = cards;
}
```

This constructor initializes a **local variable** `hand` with the cards passed as arguments. So the `cards` field is never reinitialized by this constructor.

Comment: I believe the constructor expects an array to be passed as a hard dependency so it's the responsibility of client code to make sure they pass a filled array.

Comment: And my point is that the constructor ignores the filled array passed to the constructor. And that the initialization of the field is useless, since the constructor should overwrite the cards variable with the array passed as argument.